# Why would be axions be a candidate for warm/cold dark matter?

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, axion

Axions are the current main favoured candidate for the identity of dark matter.  While their masses are sub-$\mathrm{eV}$, why is it that they would be cold or possibly warm dark matter candidates rather than being hot dark matter?  Surely they should be relativistic, considered their small masses?

Comment: It is hypothesized that they were produced non-thermally. I don't think they are the main favoured candidate currently though!

Comment: [Quick reference for everyone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axion)

Comment: It depends on the velocity of such a particle. Cold dark matter is approximated as a pressure-less fluid, and for the hot dark matter the velocity is relativistic. For warm dark matter hypothesis, from observational bounds, the velocity is of the order of 10^3 km/s for such a fluid. As you can see, [the axion can be a hot dark matter particle](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.0615.pdf).

Comment: This article http://web.mit.edu/redingtn/www/netadv/specr/345/node3.html contains a reason why axions are considered CDM despite their lightness.

Comment: @Otto They are roughly on-deck in terms of detectability. I presume they are where the searches will move in earnest if the current WIMP searches fail to turn up anything (or turn up something but it isn't enough).