# Are Axinos an attractive candidate for Dark Matter and why?

Tags: supersymmetry, dark-matter

Out of the SUSY DM candidates Gravitinos and Neutralinos are considered more likely than [Axinos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axino) however I cannot find much on these.

NB: Note the difference between axions and axinos.

Comment: The title appears to not match the "question" in the body, and seems to fit [your other question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270216/50583) better. Broad statements like "X is considered a better candidate than Y" tend to be highly-opinion based. What is the objective physics question here?

Comment: This question concerns Axinos, whereas the other concerns Axions @ACuriousMind .  I am just wondering why Axinos are not held in as high regard as Neutralinos and Gravitinos.

Comment: "In supersymmetric theories the axion has both a scalar and a fermionic superpartner. The fermionic superpartner of the axion is called the axino, the scalar superpartner is called the saxion or dilaton. They are all bundled up in a chiral superfield.  The axino has been predicted to be the lightest supersymmetric particle in such a model. In part due to this property, it is considered a candidate for dark matter." - from [this website](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axion#Supersymmetry)

Comment: Oh...it's **very** hard to read the difference between axino and axion unless one is explicitly looking for it - you might try to be mindful about that when writing such questions. Still, I'm not sure what you mean by "not held in as high regard" - someone actively working on axions will tell you very different story than someone working on other explanations. I'd prefer if you formulated a question that makes no reference to the individual preferences of physicists or what they hold in "high regard".

Comment: @ACuriousMind Let me rephrase my question; In the wider physics community, why is generally more consideration to Neutralinos and Gravitinos than Axinos as a DM candidate?   Hope this clears things up with the word Axino, i'm sorry you weren't looking for it.

Comment: Maybe because neutrinos are known to exist but axions aren't? Axinos are *a* candidate for dark matter, but I don't know about attractive.

Comment: @heather However Neutrinos would be hot DM which has completely disregarded, therefore we have to look for another candidate, of which all are purely theoretical.

Comment: No, I don't consider "why is there generally more consideration of theory X" to be an objective physics question, because that has as much to do with sociology and historical accidents as with actual scientific reasons.

Comment: @ACuriousMind So do you know why they're an attractive candidate or not?

Comment: I think what ACuriousMind is saying is that whether or not a particle/theory/whatever is "attractive" to physicists is more opinion based than anything else, and so your question isn't really a physics question.

Comment: @heather  Okay but I want to understand these opinions as to formulate a wider viewpoint to further my personal understanding of physics.

Comment: @NoahP, and what ACuriousMind is saying is that that's not a physics question but a sociology/history question that shouldn't really be asked here. Besides, I think if you ask, "tell me what people think about dark matter and axinos" - that is really broad, and that isn't really a good question either.

Comment: @heather are you sure you know what sociology is because i'm not quite sure that Axino DM really falls under that

Comment: I think it suffices to say what advantages and disadvantages do Axinos, Neutralinos and Gravitinos have :)

Anyway I'm a simple guy. I see dark matter, I up-vote.

Comment: Okay, maybe not sociology. I found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0402220) that might help

Comment: @Otto, that's a good question.

Comment: [This website](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Baryonic_vs._nonbaryonic_matter) seems very helpful...and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0504422) is the paper that is cited. The paper examines dark matter candidates, so that might be helpful.

Comment: Note that on the experimental side the "attractive candidates" are those that we have a viable technology to search for. That means WIMPs (including heavy neutrino flavors in that bin) as of right now and probably axions next up (there are technology demonstrator projects either underway to just wrapped up). I'm not the right flavor of expert but for what it might be worth I've never heard anyone talking over the detection problem for axinos.